# Is the module fully compatible with Drupal 9?

Tags: commerce, 9

If I create a new project and install The *Commerce Core* module using Composer following the instructions given from the drupalcommerce.org documentation, it would install Drupal 8 by default, not Drupal 9.

I know there are ways to work around this and install Commerce Core on top of Drupal 9. Is it fully compatible with Drupal 9?

Answer (score 1):

The project maintainers have marked it as compatible with Drupal 9 (see the [project page](https://drupal.org/project/commerce)), so yes, it should be considered compatible, and any issues encountered should be raised as bug reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the instructions given on [Installing](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/installation), those are the instructions to install Drupal 8 and the *Commerce Core* module. That doesn't mean the module isn't compatible with Drupal 9, but that the instructions haven't been updated for Drupal 9.

If `composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev` install Drupal 8, it should be sufficient to force Composer to use the *9.x-dev* version, with `composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore "9.x-dev" --stability dev`. (The package version is given after the directory where the project is created.)